# How to generate all distinct cyclic binary strings of a certain length?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, computer-science

I'm looking for a way to generate all cyclic/reflective distinct binary strings of a certain length with equal $0$s and $1$s. That is, a string $s_1$ would considered identical to some other string $s_2$ if:

- $s_1$ is a cyclic shift of $s_2$, e.g. $1000 = 0100$
- $s_1$ is a mirroring of $s_2$, e.g. $101100 = 001101$
- $s_1$ is a cyclic shift of a mirroring of $s_2$, e.g. $101100 = 100110$

I wrote a quick script to detect these and got the following (for even numbers):

4:
1100
1010

6:
010101
001011
000111

8:
11110000
11101000
11100100
11011000
11010100
11010010
11001100
10101010

Is there a name for this set ? Is there a way of quickly generating it?

Comment: You should add the requirement that the number of $1$s and $0$s is the same.  Otherwise for $4$ you also need $0000,0001,0111,1111$ and so on.

Comment: Your example for $4$ is incorrect.  Those two are cyclic shifts of each other and you need $1010$

Comment: @RossMillikan ah yeah, I copy-pasted the wrong sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are $2n$-bead black-white reversible necklaces with $n$ black beads, and they are enumerated by sequence [A005648](http://oeis.org/A005648) in the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences. The following formula is given for the number of necklaces:

$$a(n) = \left[\frac{1}{4n} \sum_{d|n} \phi(n/d)\,\binom{2d}{d}\right] + \frac12\binom{2k}{k}$$
where $k = \lfloor n/2\rfloor$.

The following Python code generates these necklaces.

```
from itertools import combinations, chain
import numpy as np

def binary_words(zeros, ones):
    n = zeros + ones
    for c in combinations(range(n), ones):
        word = np.zeros(n, dtype=int)
        word[list(c)] = 1
        yield tuple(word)

def cyclic_permute(word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        yield word[i:] + word[:i]

def dihedral_permute(word):
    return chain(cyclic_permute(word), cyclic_permute(word[::-1]))

def is_reduced(word):
    return all(word <= w for w in dihedral_permute(word))

def balanced_necklaces(n):
    return list(filter(is_reduced, binary_words(n, n)))
```